# Xamarin Forms Pop UP

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to show a pop up with buttons in it when I click a button and I want it to pop up near the button like Facebook Popup reaction when we hold on the like button. How can achieve that in Xamarin.Forms?
The image below.
[image: The pop up]

Comment: What do you mean by facebook popup reaction?

Comment: When you hold on like button on facebook it will show a pop up. I mean I want that pop up.

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of what you want?

Comment: @G.hakim I add a picture of what I want.

Comment: What you are looking for is called quick actions and I don't think anyone has done it so far in xamarin forms(In my knowledge), I would suggest you look at this : http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-quick-action-pattern-in-android/26980 and this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/60426/ios9-quick-actions-icons-uiapplicationshortcuticontype native implementations for ios and android and create your own implementation

Answer (score 5):

There are built-in popup options - Alert and Action Sheet. Both are described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/pop-ups).

To display an alert you can use:

```
var answer = await DisplayAlert ("Question?", "Would you like to play a game", "Yes", "No");
```

If you need to display multiple possible actions the user can take, use action sheet:

```
var action = await DisplayActionSheet ("ActionSheet: Send to?", "Cancel", null, "Email", "Twitter", "Facebook");
```

For something more involved you can look around GitHub as there are many third party repositories that might suit your needs. For example [this](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) looks promising.

Comment: This pop up show at the center of the screen. I want a pop up that show near my button.